# GIS Landcover/Precipitation/Geologic Faults Data for Nepal

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am doing some analysis for a project regarding disaster recovery in Nepal and I am trying to get my hands on data that is required to do the complex statistical analysis like regression. I am looking for landcover raster or vector, rainfall tables, as well as any type of raster or shapefile related to geologic faults in the region. Much of my analysis is dealing with landslides. Please be detailed in your response.

Comment: Do you need climatological rainfall data or daily values or hourly values? Do you need measured data or gridded data? What spatial resolution do you need? Please be detailed in your question.

Comment: The raster I am working with is 30x30...it's about as good as it gets in Nepal using a DEM I downloaded from Aster. I am still a student in GIS so I suppose I didn't consider or wasn't aware of all the options. I would be using the rainfall data to prescribe values to a model that determines areas prone to slope failure hazards...so I am not really sure what would be best. I would guess that measured/daily data would be best there. I am realizing half of GIS is knowing where to search for usable data...which is a skill in itself.

Comment: indeed it is. where have you looked?